# Can we go against the [flow]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

So, we have a [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow) tag whose description is:

> "Flow is the mental state of operation in which a person performing an activity is fully immersed in a feeling of energized focus, full involvement, and enjoyment in the process of the activity" - Flow (psychology) - Wikipedia
>
> "Here's the trouble. We all know that knowledge workers work best by getting into "flow", also known as being "in the zone", where they are fully concentrated on their work and fully tuned out of their environment." - The Joel Test: 12 Steps to Better Code by Joel Spolsky

Now, that sounds offtopic enough to burniate.

Can we kill the flow tag?

Facebook released [flow](https://code.prod.facebook.com/posts/1505962329687926/flow-a-new-static-type-checker-for-javascript/) today so I suggest:

- Kill the current flow tag
- Create a facebook-flow tag
- Redirect flow to facebook-flow

Comment: Who the hell created that wiki?

Comment: @Will I checked, I have _no idea_ how that was approved. here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2437716

Comment: The tag-wiki had a (maybe on-topic) previous resivion. And both the last tag-wiki and excerpt revision had two dissenters.

Comment: I think flow shouldn't be redirected to 'facebook-flow;' flow can refer to UI design and layouts. See responsive design and flow layouts. Not to mention FlowLayouts/FlowLayoutPanels in Java/android.

Comment: Looks like [tag:flowtype] became the tag for the Facebook-authored JavaScript type checker.

Comment: So... nothing happened in the last three years. I keep changing "flow" tags to "flowtype" all the time. It seems at least half the questions about Facebook's "Flow" use the "flow" tag and not the "flowtype" tag. I dared ask a question on meta about this issue - the most relevant questions in a search all rare form 2014 so I think that should be okay - but was IMMEDIATELY downvoted, so I deleted it. Ridiculous!

Comment: There are now only 7 questions left in [tag:flow], and all of them are off-topic/close-worthy. I cast a close vote on each remaining one; hopefully they'll get closed so we can then delete them or let them Roomba.

Comment: @TylerH and it took only 9 years to do!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Dangit, not quite 6-8 somethings... :-(

Comment: My findings in case it gets created again: A lot of tech-specific tags have been created (e.g. kotlin, vaadin, mule, salesforce) in that time and should be used instead. In more recent usage, [tag:ms-flow], which maps to [tag:power-automate] has been trending as well. It was also used for [tag:max-flow] and [tag:dataflow-diagram] on occasion. The ones that meant [tag:control-flow] were usually low-quality/closeable.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, this tag definitely needs a cleanup. It has lots of different meanings in different contexts:

- [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout) (CSS, Java-Swing, various GUI toolkits)
- [flowchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flowchart) (here it's redundant and should be removed)
- [control-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/control-flow) (here it's redundant and should be removed)
- as [traffic flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_flow_(computer_networking)) in practical [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking)
- or as [flow-networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) in theoretical [graph-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithm), like [max-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/max-flow) or [minimum-cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimum-cut)

There is a tool from Facebook, you can use [flowtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flowtype) for questions about it.

Also, a few frameworks use the name for a component of them:

- [typo3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3). Should be retagged to existing [typo3-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-flow)
- [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) (this is what the [original tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7229597/2) was about)
- [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf)
- [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring)
- …

---

So, Facebook released a tool with the same name today? Welcome to the club, but no need to take action. Now to your options:

> Kill the current flow tag

Why not. I'd suggest to create new tags [flow-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow-layout), [traffic-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traffic-flow) and [flow-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow-network), retag, and burn the rest. Maybe create framework-specific tags if their usage is significant.

> Create a [facebook-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-flow) tag

[flowtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flowtype) is now used for that.

> Redirect flow to facebook-flow

Definitely not.

Comment: Dangit. I had practically this exact same post 90% finished when I saw yours pop up. Agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: @AirThomas: Additions are welcome :-)

Comment: I have retagged [typo3-flow] and [spring-webflow] questions.

Comment: Re: the suggested new tags: How about [layout-flow], [traffic-flow] and [network-flow] for consistency? (This has the advantage of sounding more 'natural language', and the disavantage that users don't get them as suggestions when they start typing flow...)

Comment: @JanDoggen Afair they would get them as suggestions? But imo they are not more natural. The `flow` is should not be the noun, those tags would be about layouts and networks. (Disclaimer: I'm no native speaker either)

Comment: Note that [tag:facebook-flow] no longer exists, and [tag:flowtype] should be used. [Which tag should I use for Facebook Flow questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359074/which-tag-should-i-use-for-facebook-flow-questions)

Comment: Other flowy stuff: [Windows Workflow Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation), [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), [GitFlow](https://www.gitflow.com/), [Apache Airflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Airflow), [MLflow](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow), [Webflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webflow#Overview), and [Dialogflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogflow).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I doubt any of those would be tagged [flow], are they?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in agreement with [Bergi's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277196/2359271) but there's one area I think deserves just a bit more attention, which is what to do with all those [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow) questions that are about Mule. They represent [about 25% of the tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflow%5D+mule), a significantly larger portion than the other frameworks Bergi mentioned.

I think the best option is to **make sure they're tagged [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) and leave them alone otherwise.** [4 out of 5 questions tagged "mule" contain the word "flow"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmule%5D+flow), so adding a framework-specific tag like [mule-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-flow) wouldn't add useful meaning or selectivity. (There's also nothing worth saving in the original wiki revision – it's just a description copied from the tool's website.)

Comment: [mule-flow] exists now.